# golang - how to access internals of struct (reflection?)

Tags: reflection, go

I need to add attributes to a log15 logger, but if I inadvertently add one twice it will appear twice. So, I want to add logic to see if the attribute is already populated and skip the action if it is.

Here's what I get when I output the log object:

```
log="&{ctx:[field1 val1 field2 val2 field3 val3 field2 val2] h:0xc82052c1e0}"
```

How can I access that 'ctx' field and validate when my value is already there? I've tried some reflection tricks and can get the data type, but I can't figure out how to get the value.

Comment: You might want to at least provide some code or something or you're gonna end up having your question down voted

Answer (score 1):

I will first go through what you asked for exactly, that is access the attributes stored in the logger's context.

Reflection in Go is based on `Type` and `Value`. You do not have access to any data using `Type`, you just have information about the type (surprise !). So, here you have to use the `Value` side of reflection.

However, the problem is that the `ctx` field of the logger is not exported, so it's not possible to access it directly. However, using a bit of unsafe operations make it doable.

Here is the code:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "reflect"
    "unsafe"
)

type logger struct {
    ctx []interface{}
}

type Logger interface {
    Populate(ctx ...interface{})
}

func NewLogger() Logger {
     return &logger{}
}

func (l *logger) Populate(ctx ...interface{}) {
    l.ctx = ctx
}

func main() {
    log := NewLogger()
    log.Populate(42, "42", 84, "84")
    fmt.Println(log)
    // &{[42 42 84 84]}
    v := reflect.ValueOf(log).Elem()
    field := v.FieldByName("ctx")
    ar := *(*[]interface{})(unsafe.Pointer(field.UnsafeAddr()))

    for _, i := range ar {
        fmt.Println(i)
    }
    // 42 42 84 84
}
```

[Go playground](https://play.golang.org/p/mv2-MoR75Q)

**Do NEVER do that**

The code works, and produces what you expect. However, what you are doing is using reflection and unsafe operations to get values from an **unexported** struct of a **third-party** library. My english is not good enough to express properly how **bad** this is.

If you don't want to have twice the same attribute in the logger, do not put it twice in the first place, it's far better and easier than maintaining the code that's above.

If you still do not trust yourself enough for this, then wrap the logger in a struct where you store the attributes contained in the logger. At least it will be something you have your hands on, and do the same job.

So, you're free to use this code. But if you want to do yourself a favor, you won't use it in that case.

Comment: Regarding why it's a bad idea: the internal structure of the logger might change in the next release or 10 releases from now, making your code break entirely. Worse, if you update your code to accommodate this change, suddenly a person with the new version of your code and the old version of the logger finds their code doesn't work. The reverse situation where this version of your code and a new version of the logger code that is incompatible are used is equally as bad. Of course, it might not change at all, but that doesn't mean it's a good idea.